Lambda creation problem with Cloudformation
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Creating single submissions download file from S3 daily files and input put parameters

Transform:
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  GiveawayInsertFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ../lambdas
      FunctionName: giveaway_insert
      Handler: giveaway_insert_lambda/src/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs20.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 10
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Description: Inserting giveaway submissions into the database
      Policies:
        - Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: logs:CreateLogGroup
              Resource: arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:891377358932:*
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - logs:CreateLogStream
                - logs:PutLogEvents
              Resource: arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:891377358932:log-group:/aws/lambda/giveaway_insert:*
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: dynamodb:PutItem
              Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:891377358932:table/*

  GiveawayInsertFunctionUrl:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Url
    Properties:
      AuthType: NONE
      TargetFunctionArn: !GetAtt GiveawayInsertFunction.Arn
      Cors:
        AllowOrigins:
          - "*"
        AllowMethods:
          - "*"
        AllowHeaders:
          - "*"
        MaxAge: 600

This is my template for creating lambda with sam. Everything goes well, and lambda with function url created, but when I'm requesting the function with the given url, getting forbidden, 403 response ({"Message":"Forbidden"}).
But when I edit the function url and save without any change, the 403 error disappears, and everything works well.

Can you clarify what you mean by "when I edit the function url"?

@jarmod I just open my lambda function in AWS admin console, go to Configuration/FunctionURL/Edit and just save without changing anything there

What version of AWS and SAM CLIs are you using? Can you use CloudFormation Stack Drift to check what changes in the function URL or the function itself after you save?

@AllanChua
Sam version: 1.116.0
Drift status: IN_SYNC
